# Does the verse וארשתיך... count as the language of Kiddushin?

Tags: language, kiddushin-eirusin

Following the discussion about different formulations of non-Orthodox Ketubahs on this site.

A couple wishes to find a milder non-Orthodox formulation of the Kiddushin. So they chose that the groom will tell to his bride the full Posuk (Hosea 2, 21):

> "וְאֵרַשְׂתִּיךְ לִי לְעוֹלָם וְאֵרַשְׂתִּיךְ לִי בְּצֶדֶק וּבְמִשְׁפָּט וּבְחֶסֶד וּבְרַחֲמִים"
>
> (*be careful with the translation*) And I will espouse you forever: I will espouse you with righteousness and justice, And with goodness and mercy.

Does it count (nowadays) as a language of Kiddushin (instead of הרי את מקודשת לי)? Does it depend on a specific community?

I don't ask if it bounds (depends on witnesses, and surroundings and a ring etc, only the language.

---

There are many "catches" in this scenario: it is a whole Posuk (maybe doesn't count), the language is unclear if it is past or present or future (ו' ההיוך), if this language is considered "spoken", it describes the action, not the state of the bride (את מקודשת) and more.

Comment: He needs to give a that of value, not just Tzedek Mishpat Chesed and Rachamim (not sure how to give those)

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought the "וארשתיך" part will suffice as that the main point.

Comment: If you just want to ask about the root ארס then do so without complications

Comment: @DoubleAA It is far more complicated than that - ו ההיפוך, it describes the action, not her state etc.

Comment: @AlBerko Then at least cut down your question to the first half of the passuk, וארשתיך לי לעולם and stop there. (FWIW הרי את מאורסת לי is a perfectly valid language for Kiddushin.)

Comment: @DonielF Maybe, if it counts as a whole posuk it is different, or maybe other words will tell, IDK

Comment: There’s also the concept that if you’re discussing Kiddushin with her and then give her the ring, we pasken that the Kiddushin is binding, since she can infer from context that that’s the intent behind your giving it.

Comment: If they don't accept the halachic concept of kiddushin probably no phraseology will accomplish it.  They don't have daas for it.

Comment: @DonielF While it's true, That isn't the question, it is strictly about the language.